# Libgdx Clearing Screen benefits

Tags: java, libgdx, game-development

I looked a lot in the internet but somehow couldn't find any benefits to always clear the screen in the render method or didn't understand it very well.

So what's the benefit from clearing the screen wouldn't clearing somehow cause the game to draw everything from scratch each time the render method is called?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a game with at least one moving thing, not clearing the screen will cause the sprite (if you're using a sprite) of the thing to be in every place it has been in past frames. Usually you clear the screen to remove past drawn stuff and redraw with updated positions. You could program some logic to know whether stuff has moved and avoid clearing the screen but I don't think clearing the screen's computational cost is  high enough for the effort.

Below is an example of the effect caused by not clearing the screen each frame.
[image]

**Edit:** As Tenfour04 stated, there is another good reason for clearing the screen: **Perfomance**.

> Libgdx, like almost all game engines, uses double buffering, which means that while one frame is being rendered to screen, it is already drawing the next frame to another frame buffer. If you don't clear the screen, it has to wait and then copy the contents of the first buffer into the second before it can start drawing to it. So it wastes GPU time copying and also prevents the multitasking that saves some time

Comment: Hi Thanks, I tried to delete clearing the screen part to see what happens, with the thing you said in mind but my sprite moved normal do you mean "the sprite is in every place" it's on the screen or in the memory

Comment: The sprite should be on the screen multiple times. If you don't see that it should be because you have a background image that's hiding what's really happening behind (EDIT: I just tested this)

Comment: I load a map from tiled could it be because of that?

Comment: Yes, specially if the map/tiles cover the whole screen, if you want to see what not clearing the screen is like, try commenting the line where you draw the map and draw a simple square moving in a direction. I'll try to attach an image to my answer

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer I know understand what the benefits of clearing the screen is :)

Comment: Glad to help! if you could upvote my answer it would really help me stay motivated to keep helping :3

Comment: @user11343077 please accept this answer if it solved your problem. (The tick under the vote buttons)

Comment: This is the more obvious reason, but even if you were drawing a background that covers the whole screen, you would still want to clear it for performance reasons. Libgdx, like almost all game engines, uses double buffering, which means that while one frame is being rendered to screen, it is already drawing the next frame to another frame buffer. If you don't clear the screen, it has to wait and then copy the contents of the first buffer into the second before it can start drawing to it. So it wastes GPU time copying and also prevents the multitasking that saves some time.